# angularjs ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here am trying to use google map's api in my app for location picker. By accesing this url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
```

Though this is working in local solution its not working in my main app.It is giving an error

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined angular.js:13294
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM6558 locator.js:87)
at fire (jquery.js:3187)
at Object.self.add [as done] (jquery.js:3246)
at jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3496)
at Object.<anonymous> (VM6558 locator.js:86)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4625)
at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4464)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4625)
at angular.js:4424
```

Order of the Scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/libs/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Comment: so, see another errors in console, also possibly google script load after angular

Comment: Thanks fo d rly.. But no other errors in console except for this..And scripts are in order..

Comment: can you provide working sample  that reproduce problem? for example here in snippet, or in jsfiddle&

Comment: Provide the order of all scripts please

Comment: I faced the same problem with ngmap and solved it by changing the order of script loading.

Answer (score 0):

```js
vm.initialize = function(){
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.772573, 106.698000)
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('order-detail-map'), mapOptions);
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(vm.order.customer.address.position.lat, vm.order.customer.address.position.long);
        setTimeout(function(){
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          map.setCenter(latlng);
        }, 50);

        myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          draggable: false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: "i/marker.png",
          position:latlng
        });
        myMarker.setMap(map);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', vm.initialize());
```